# Niche Templating Engine for Batch Jobs

Tags: java, scala, batch-processing, templating

First of all start off by saying this is more of an exploratory question more than a technical problem. I feel it doesn't belong to Code Review because there's nothing to review. I'm just trying to figure out the best approach to take.

My requirement is to build a batch process that can process user-defined files. These files usually come from external sources, so the filenames are not standard. One requirement that's causing me some headaches is supporting arbitrary dates in the filenames. And since these are batch job definitions that run on particular intervals, the definition has to be flexible enough to support it.

---

### For example, one definition might be

---

- **File1_Type1_{CurrentDate in YYMMDD}**
- **File1_Type2_{CurrentDate in YYYYMMDD}**
- **File1_Type3_Static_Text**

So basically, I feel like I need a full-fledged template engine in order to support these cases. However, that sounds like huge overkill, so I'm interested to hear people's thoughts on this.

Since I'm focusing on Java/Scala, I've found this library

https://scalate.github.io/scalate/documentation/ssp-reference.html

If we let users create ssp files like so:

```
#import(java.util.Date)

File1_Type1_${new Date}
```

then it gives the user full control over the entire formatting. But feels overkill to me? Or not? Welcome any feedback.

Comment: `File1_Type1_${new Date}` - why would you need a "full fledged" template engine for this? String literals in triple quotes, with `${}` seems completely sufficient here.

Answer (score 0):

There are a huge number in the Java space.   I've used Apache velocity and https://freemarker.apache.org/.

I'm not aware of anything in the Scala space, but it would be an intriguing idea.